# How to read/parse correctly GA Custom Variable?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

I'm sorry for possible duplicate (I did not find answer)

I need to read value from cookie page, that is actually 'google analytics Custom Variable'. We set it like that

```
tracker._setCustomVar(1, 'myvar', 'myvalue', 1);
```

as result I have variable __utmv with some value in cookie, i.e.

```
12345678.|1=myvar=myvalue=1
```

I'm wondering if I simply can take everything after 'myvar=' and before '=1'? Maybe there is an 'official' way how it should be done?
I'm not sure if that format will be always same/similar and if I can expect that value ends with '=1'? and if so, what if my value has substring '=1', should I care about that?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find some smart way how to solve my problem, instead I simply parse string and took value from it.